# How to match 12h time in text string

Tags: php, regex

I have the strings below in a feed. I need to match the bold portion and store it in a variable:

1. Ramdom Event Name **12:30PM to 1:30PM**
2. Ramdom Event Name again **2:30PM**

**UPDATE:**

I used the solution provided by @cryptic.

Here are the result:

```
 $titles = array( 
                "*~Svet~* 12:30PM to 1:30PM",
                "Basketball (M and W) vs Cleveland State 6:00PM",
                "Christmas for the Kids Celebration! 2:00PM to 4:00PM"
            );

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    //get date
    preg_match('/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)( to \d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)?/i', $title, $match);
    //get title
    $cleanTitle = preg_split('/([0-1][0-9]|[0-9]):?([0-5][0-9])/', $title);

echo "<p>Title: ".$cleanTitle[0]."<br />Time: ".$match[0]."</p>"; 

}
```

**//Output**

Title: *~Svet~*
Time: 12:30PM to 1:30PM

Title: Basketball (M and W) vs Cleveland State
Time: 6:00PM

Title: Christmas for the Kids Celebration!
Time: 2:00PM to 4:00PM

Comment: I have tried using preg_split but I am not getting the results I need. 

$cleanTitle = preg_split('/([0-1][0-9]|[0-9]):?([0-5][0-9])/', $title);

Comment: Try being even more specific. 1. Should "to" also be matched? 2. Is the relation to the name important? 3. Is it the time parts you need to store, or are there more information you need to get from it (e.g. time range vs. time stamp)?

Comment: 1 - "to" should also be matched
2 - The relationship to the name is not important
3 - I just need the highlighted portion of the string

Comment: @jfurtado please see my example it will match the bold sections including 'to'

Comment: 4. Is it possible for the "Random Event Name" to contain strings that are valid time stamps? If so, a solution will have to take that into account as well.

Comment: Please update your question to show: The code you've used, the test data you've run it against, and how your results differ from what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// String example 1
$string = 'Ramdom Event Name 12:30PM to 1:30PM';
preg_match('/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)( to \d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)?/i', $string, $match);
echo $match[0]; // outputs 12:30PM to 1:30PM

// String example 2
$string = 'Ramdom Event Name again 2:30PM';
preg_match('/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)( to \d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)?/i', $string, $match);
echo $match[0]; // outputs 2:30PM
```

same regex expression will match both string examples, and will also fetch the 'to' portion as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using the following `regex`.
`/\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:a|p)m(?: to \d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:a|p)m)*/i`